# Charindex Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a column with values similar to `1.adc.ssg`
How do I get the `adc` and `ssg` using `charindex`.

```
select distinct 
       lower(substring(tx_id,0,charindex('.',tx_id))) as t1,
       lower(substring(tx_id, charindex('.',tx_id)+1,len(tx_id))) as t2 
from #test
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `split_part`?

```
select split_part(tx_id,'.',2), split_part(tx_id,'.',3)
```

Comment: @ms93 Glad it worked. You can accept the answer by checking the tick mark